# how can i redirect my user to the "Home" page When user clicks the register button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

Currently when user clicks the Register button in register form i am sending the him/her back to the "index" view  using "RedirectToAction".

```
        public IActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser()
            { UserName = loginViewModel.UserName };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync
                (user, loginViewModel.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        return View(loginViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, it's doing that by `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`, so, what is exactly the problem you are facing?

Comment: HI, does `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` get called? You can test it with a debugger; if it isn't probably your registration failed.

Comment: Problem is that when user click the button data does't in database and user still in register view not go to the index which i mention

Comment: Yes, so my guess is that `await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, loginViewModel.Password);` fails. Please test the result with a debugger. Maybe you are using a too short password or something like that.

Comment: did you put a breakpoint and see what is the problem? for example are you sure that your modelstate is valid?

Comment: Yes i sure Model state is valid

Comment: Probably, the result.Succeeded is being evaluated BEFORE the async method has actually completed its course -after all, that’s what asynchronous operations are there for- so it will always be false.